# Problem installing Solaris Studio

Tags: package-management, solaris

I was following instructions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E77782_01/html/E77785/gouaw.html#scrolltoc), but unfortunately, trying to do the last command:

```
$ pkg contents -m sunpro-incorporation | grep 0.175
```

didn't yield anything.

**NOTE:** I'm trying to install it on Oracle Solaris 11 on x86_64 VM.

P.S.:
Below are the last commands from the session:

```
root@solaris:~# pkg list sunpro-incorporation
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation         0.5.11-0.174.0.0.0.0.0     i--
root@solaris:~# beadm list
BE        Active Mountpoint Space   Policy Created
--        ------ ---------- -----   ------ -------
solaris   -      -          182.00M static 2018-08-14 19:31
solaris-1 NR     /          6.65G   static 2018-08-14 23:06
root@solaris:~# pkg info developer-studio-utilities
pkg: info: no packages matching the following patterns you specified are
installed on the system.  Try specifying -r to query remotely:

        developer-studio-utilities
root@solaris:~# pkg info -r developer-studio-utilities
          Name: group/feature/developer-studio-utilities
       Summary: Developer Support For Oracle Solaris Studio
   Description: Tools and runtime support libraries for use with Oracle Solaris
                Studio
      Category: Development/C (org.opensolaris.category.2008)
                Development/C++ (org.opensolaris.category.2008)
                Development/Fortran (org.opensolaris.category.2008)
                Meta Packages/Group Packages (org.opensolaris.category.2008)
         State: Not installed
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 0.5.11
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: 0.175.3.3.0.2.0
Packaging Date: November 17, 2015 03:16:25 AM
          Size: 5.56 kB
          FMRI:
pkg://solaris/group/feature/developer-studio-utilities@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.3.0.2.0:20151117T031625Z
root@solaris:~# pkg install -nv developer-studio-utilities
           Packages to install:         7
     Estimated space available: 480.75 GB
Estimated space to be consumed: 216.59 MB
       Create boot environment:        No
Create backup boot environment:        No
          Rebuild boot archive:        No

Changed packages:
solaris
  developer/openmpi-15
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.174.0.0.0.0.0:20110921T185134Z
  developer/xopen/xcu4
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.174.0.0.0.0.0:20110921T185246Z
  group/feature/developer-studio-utilities
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.3.0.2.0:20151117T031625Z
  network/open-fabrics
    None -> 1.5.3,5.11-0.175.0.10.1.0.0:20120918T161500Z
  service/picl
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.173.0.0.0.1.0:20110826T161600Z
  system/header
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.175.0.10.1.0.0:20120918T163136Z
  system/library/studio-runtime
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.3.0.2.0:20151117T031646Z
root@solaris:~# pkg install -v sunpro-incorporation developer-studio-utilities
           Packages to install:         7
     Estimated space available: 480.75 GB
Estimated space to be consumed: 216.59 MB
       Create boot environment:        No
Create backup boot environment:        No
          Rebuild boot archive:        No

Changed packages:
solaris
  developer/openmpi-15
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.174.0.0.0.0.0:20110921T185134Z
  developer/xopen/xcu4
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.174.0.0.0.0.0:20110921T185246Z
  group/feature/developer-studio-utilities
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.3.0.2.0:20151117T031625Z
  network/open-fabrics
    None -> 1.5.3,5.11-0.175.0.10.1.0.0:20120918T161500Z
  service/picl
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.173.0.0.0.1.0:20110826T161600Z
  system/header
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.175.0.10.1.0.0:20120918T163136Z
  system/library/studio-runtime
    None -> 0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.3.0.2.0:20151117T031646Z
DOWNLOAD                                  PKGS       FILES    XFER (MB)
Completed                                  7/7   3318/3318    19.6/19.6

PHASE                                        ACTIONS
Install Phase                              3771/3771

PHASE                                          ITEMS
Package State Update Phase                       7/7
Image State Update Phase                         2/2
root@solaris:~# pkg contents -m sunpro-incorporation | grep 0.175
root@solaris:~# pkgchk -v pkg:/developer/base-developer-utilities
WARNING: no pathnames were associated with
<pkg:/developer/base-developer-utilities>
```

P.S.2:

The third command on my system displays following:

```
root@sparcbox:~# pkg list sunpro-incorporation
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
consolidation/sunpro/sunpro-incorporation         0.5.11-0.174.3.9.0.2.0     i--
```

which is different from what is on the page. (0.174 vs 0.175).

I don't know whether I should be worried and will get a not upto-date repository.

Any idea?

Comment: What exact version of Solaris 11? What's the output from `uname -rsv`? Could you post the output from `pkg publisher`?  The `org.opensolaris.category.2008` in your output looks wrong.  Oracle support for OpenSolaris is long dead, and the `2008` there puts that at literally a decade old.  `developer-studio` and `sunpro` are also old names for what you'd see as `solarisstudio` in current releases.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

After performing the full system update everything seems normal. I will continue with install and if something will fail, I will get back here.